# How can I use start-stop-daemon to start a mpi task?

Tags: linux, shell, mpi, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I use `demo.sh` to start a daemon mpi task:

```
#! /bin/sh
if ! kill -0 $(cat pid) > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  /sbin/start-stop-daemon -p pid -m pid --start --background --exec mpirun -n 2 a.out
fi
```

But it can not work, how can I use `start-stop-daemon` to start a mpi job?

Comment: What is the result you're seeing? When you say, "it doesn't work", we need more information to try to help you.

Comment: @WesleyBland I doesn't get any error, but daemon do not started.

Comment: Why do you not just use the regular mpiexec/mpirun command?

Comment: @WesleyBland I want to start a daemon as a service